# Can I run two mysql commands when connecting to a docket container?

Tags: mysql, docker

I have a brief script to connect to a docker container and login:

`docker exec -it mysql mysql --password=password`

The first `mysql` is the name of the container, the second is the first command I'd like to run.

This works fine, I end up with a mysql prompt inside the container, but then I have to run something like:

`use mydatabase`

I'd rather do this as a one-liner, just to save time. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run multiple commands in one line on a container you can write something like this:
`docker exec -it <container> <bash|sh> -c "<command1> && <command2> && <command3>"`

In your case, for instance:
`docker exec -it mysql sh -c "mysql --password=password && use mydatabase"`

Using `&&` delimiter instead of `;` will execute the next command only if the previous one has completed successfully (0 exit code)

Comment: Thanks, appreciated. I got it working with:

    docker exec -it mysql mysql --password=password dbname

Which also seemed to work, but your answer will be handy if I need to add more commands.